# exit if background command fails in shell script

Tags: bash, shell-script

I am sure this has been covered but not sure how to find the answer:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

set -e;
false &
wait;
echo "lol"
```

if we run this, we get "lol".

Is there a way to exit the script if the background command (in this case "false") exits with non-zero?

In this case, `set -e;` does not seem to prevent the script from continuing if a command exits with non-zero, if that command is run in the background.

Comment: I guess `trap` is one way to do this, but it would be nice to do this without using `trap` if possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using a recent version of bash (I think this was introduced in bash 4), then you can use `wait -n`.

Otherwise, you can pass `wait` an argument with the pid of the background process you started, which is returned in `$!` right after you do.

See the [documentation of the wait command](https://tiswww.case.edu/php/chet/bash/bashref.html#index-wait) for more details on return status of the `wait` command.

This should do it:

```
set -e
false &
wait -n
echo "lol"
```

And this is fine too:

```
set -e
false &
background_pid=$!
wait "${background_pid}"
echo "lol"
```